# Why I am getting "uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionHelper" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't have a Session model though, only User and Task ones.

**app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    session[:user_id] = nil
    self.current_user = nil
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in to access this page."
  end

end
```

I included SessionHelper in application controller.

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionHelper
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tasks

  attr_accessor :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :first_name, presence: true,
            length: {maximum: 20}
  validates :last_name,  presence: true,
            length: {maximum: 40}
  validates :email, presence: true,
            format: {with: EMAIL_REGEX},
            uniqueness:  {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, presence: true,
            confirmation: true,
            length: {within: 6..40}

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)

    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  private
    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}") if self.new_r

      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(pass)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{self.salt}--#{pass}")
    end

  end
```

What's a problem can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo, it should be `SessionsHelper` and not `SessionHelper`

```
 include SessionsHelper
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was completely going mad. thanks

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko Please mark an answer as correct if it was helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept the answer! :)